# Center VideoView in landscape mode

Tags: android, center, android-videoview

How can I center a `VideoView` in landscape mode? I tried this: on Manifest file I have :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and on my Activity I have this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lv= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lv.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
    myVideoView.setLayoutParams(lv);
    myVideoView.setVideoPath(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/BouyguesImages"
                        + "37" + "/" + "89Video");

    myVideoView.requestFocus();
```

and this VideoView I add it as a View to a RelativeLayout :

```
 rr = new RelativeLayout(this);
 rr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
 rr.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

The result of my code is that my video is playing only in the top part of the screen and at the bottom the screen is white (relativelayout's color). I want to fit the VideoView on screen, so to have a small part white on the bottom of the screen, and on top of the screen to. How to do this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put it in a `LinearLayout` instead and set it's gravity to `CENTER`, or just put `CENTER_IN_PARRENT` in your `addRule()` method of `RelativeLayout` :)

Good luck!

Comment: is not working...I tried this before but no change and I don't understand why :?

Comment: Try to call invalidate() on the RelativeLayout too

Comment: It works without invalidate...my mistache was that I was adding incorrect the VideoView.

Comment: Nice one. But if i want to achive same thing with xml code then what should to do ?