# Android landscape videoview on the center

Tags: android-layout

i am developing android app. i need to play video in landscape mode and videoview should be in center of the screen, but it is playing the video in left corner of the screen. This is my code,

```
 <VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoView1"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center">



         <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

         <!-- Put Your Admob Layout here and it will work as you want. -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Update

If you want to do it using Java code [then refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471618/center-videoview-in-landscape-mode).

Comment: -Thank you so much, its working fine :) i need admob ads to be display in top of the videoview. it is not working with this. can u please help me reg this?

Comment: See updated layout with where to put your admob layout. It will help you. And accept the answer if your issue solve with it So it can help others.

Comment: This solution works pretty well to center a the video inside the VideoView!

Comment: A very good solution, thank you so much. One small issue. This disables the `android:background` option in the RelativeView. I want the background black when I watch a video, is that possible?