# How play video on VideoView inside ViewPager from server

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpage

I try to develop an app that **retrieve videos from server** and play on videoview inside viewpager, video from raw folder is worked fine but their are 2 issues:

- 1: some video isn't played. or black activity show.
- 2: video is not stop when Page is scrolled.

so how to use URL instead of `

```
android.resource://mypackagename/video1.mp4
```

and how to pause/stop when PageIsChanged. any tutorial or any hits i will be thankful for that.

**Here my code is [Source Code](http://topappstopgames.com/projects/ViewPagerVideoFromServer.zip)**

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    static int[] arrayvid;
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
            String[] population, int[] flag, int[] arrayvid) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.arrayvid = arrayvid;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rank.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtrank;
        TextView txtcountry;
        TextView txtpopulation;
        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VVExe);

        txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
        txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
        txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context, false);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }

    public void pausevideo() {
        mVideoView.stopPlayback();

    }

    public void play(int position) {
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri
                .parse("android.resource://mypackagename/"
                        + arrayvid[position]));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    String[] rank;
    private ImageButton play;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;
    public int position;
    int[] arrayvid;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);
        play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAB);
        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

        country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
                "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                "Russia", "Japan" };

        population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
                R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
                R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
                R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

        arrayvid = new int[] { R.raw.basiccrunch, R.raw.bicyclecrunch,
                R.raw.reversecrunch, R.raw.longarmcrunch,
                R.raw.crossovercrunch, R.raw.rightobliquecrunch,
                R.raw.leftobliquecrunch, R.raw.halfcurl,
                R.raw.verticallegcrunch, R.raw.plank };

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country,
                population, flag, arrayvid);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isRunning) {
                    ((ViewPagerAdapter) adapter).play(position);
                    isRunning = false;
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausee);
                } else {
                    ((ViewPagerAdapter) adapter).pausevideo();
                    isRunning = true;
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playy);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

}

**viewpager_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rank"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/country"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/population"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:padding="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VVExe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.9"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**viewpager_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="8.6" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnprevAB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/prevsel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlayAB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/playsel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNextAB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/nextsel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I think it is better to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`. In this scenario you do not need `OnPageChangeListener` any more and you can use fragment life cycle callback methods like `onResume` and `onPause` to play or pause your video.

> and how to pause/stop when PageIsChanged. any tutorial or any hits i
>   will be thankful for that.

You can use below links to understand how to use this adapter then you can create your own logic with a help of fragment life cycle method.

[Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter Example](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/)

[FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [FrameViedoView](https://github.com/mklimek/FrameVideoView) which improves performance for playing videos.

It works also for `ViewPager`.

**How to use it?**

Add `http://bright.github.io/maven-repo/` to your repositories:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://bright.github.io/maven-repo/"
    }
}
```

and then declare a dependency inside a module:

```
dependencies {
    compile('mateuszklimek.framevideoview:framevideoview:1.1.0@aar')
    //other dependencies
}
```

In [examples](https://gist.github.com/mklimek/1a7e5497292b9d945ef1e143d152e312) you can find how to use it inside a simple `Activity`.

Read my [blog post](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/frame-video-view/) about `FrameVideoView`.

Comment: @Attaullah what do you mean by that?

Comment: examples link is dead

Answer (score 1):

1. To detect if `ViewPager` is **scrolling/changing page** you just need to attach an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to your `ViewPager`.
2. To **play a video from a remote URL** you can use the standard `MediaController`/`MediaPlayer`. Take a look at [this tutoria](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/)l.

Comment: [my source code](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/ViewPagerVideoFromServer.zip)

Answer (score 1):

```
 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

           //do the needful action

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.println("selected " + position);
   //do the needful action
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access your video from your OnPageChangeListener.
Has to do it you have to:

`view.setTag("view"+position);` in your `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`

And after you can get it back from the OnPageChangeListener:

```
View viewTag = viewPager.findViewWithTag("view" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

and then

```
VideoView videoViewTag = (VideoView)viewTag.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
```