# VideoView does not fill the entire screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a short introductory video for my application. Since it is a game, first I created a theme to hide the action bar and go full-screen.

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" parent="AppTheme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, I created a layout with only a `VideoView`:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView_intro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Lastly, I played the video by the following code:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_intro);
    v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.intro));
    /* This line had a code snippet for event handling, unrelated to this question */
    v.start();
}
```

I succeeded at playing the video, but the VideoView had a small margin at the bottom. I assume it matches the height of the notification bar. How can I get rid of that margin?

**EDIT:** I don't know whether this information is needed, but the activity is forced as landscape. Also, I target all android devices from API level 8, so the solution must be compatible with API Level 8.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <activity
        android:name="org.package.name.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I guess the fastest way is to apply a bottom margin with a negative value. Try it

Comment: @Maver1ck Tried `android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"`. Result was negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I became a fool when I came up with this mind.

The problem was not about the notification bar. Instead, it was about the aspect ratio of the video.

The video was sized 480×272. It had the aspect ratio of approx. 1.7647. On the other hand, the usable screen dimension of Galaxy Nexus was 1184×720, which had the aspect ratio of approx. 1.6444. So, basically the video was "longer" than the screen.

I didn't find out the cause because:
1) Curiously the height of the margin nearly matched the height of the notification bar, and
2) Since the video was a recording of a system which had narrower screen than the phone, I didn't believe that would be the cause. (Encoder broke the supposed aspect ratio.)

To conclude, what I should look into is this article: [Center VideoView in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471618/center-videoview-in-landscape-mode)

The lesson is, don't get into your hypothesis too much.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet might be to create your own VideoView subclass, override the [onMeasure(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) method and have that grab the screen dimensions and modify the VideoView height/width to match the correct height/width for your device.

If you don't wish to do that, then your other options that could be easier would be to launch the video in a fullscreen Dialog or you can set the LayoutParams to a static size generated at runtime:

```
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_intro);
v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.intro));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

v.start();
```

Comment: Actually my cause of the problem was somewhere else, but your answer had been helpful to understand the system features. However, since the code introduces programmatic ambiguity, I proposed a modification.

Comment: @ArleCamille Oh, you probably had imported LayoutParams from a different package already. I'm not sure I accepted the edit correctly though...

Answer (score 1):

```
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_intro);
v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.intro));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

v.start();`enter code here`

this code worked correctly
```

Comment: Hi, you should really explain why your answer is better than the accepted one. Especially when posting to such an old answer.

Comment: actually I don't know where to write comment for that old answer.. so, I added that as new answer

Comment: You need to earn more reputation in order to comment.